# PHP Pass variables between PHP files

Tags: php, html

I have a DB connection in a connection.php file.
With 
"require_once"
I include the connection function in a second .php file.
In this second .php file I call another function from an another .php file and I would like to pass the connecction variable to this function.
In main file.php i have this:

```
    require_once("connection.php");
    require_once("print.php");

    DBconnection(); //Standard connection to a DB
    print("connection");
```

In connection.php i have:

```
    function DBconnection()
    {
      $connection= new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

      if ($connection->connect_errno) 
      {
       echo "$connection->connect_error . ".";
       exit();
      } 
     }
```

Can I pass the connection variable from connection.php to print("connection")?
print("connection") is a function that print something from the DB choosen from connection.php

Comment: have your function `return $connection;`

Comment: then do something like `$myConnection = DBconnection();`

Answer (score 0):

So you need to create a function, which you have but below is an example:

```
function functionName($your, $variables, $here)
{
 //code 
}
```

Then you would pass variables into it like so...

```
functionName($your, $variables, $here);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't returning a value, so if you want to pass that object back to the calling code, you just need to `return` it:

```
function DBconnection()
{
    $connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

    if ($connection->connect_errno) {
        echo $connection->connect_error . " . ";
        exit;
    }

    return $connection;
}
```

Then, just store the function result to a variable so you can use it later:

```
require_once("connection.php");
require_once("print.php");

$db = DBconnection(); //Standard connection to a DB
```

Comment: Good, and it only took 5 weeks.. :-)